# Unity Launcher resets on Reboot and Unity Tweak Tool no longer working

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, unity-tweak-tool

I have a new issue to report. As of this morning, on startup, my entire Ubuntu system looked a little different. What I discovered was that my Unity Launcher had reset to their primal defaults (i.e. files / firefox /libre writer/ amazon/ etc). Second issue I notice was that none of my settings applied to the Unity Tweak Tool no longer work. Hot Corners are no longer activated, animations are re-enabled, and many other settings I have disable upon install.

Now, granted, I have no time today to do clean install, but that seems to be the only solution thus far. Unfortunately, this would require hours of backup and other tedious notes for all software that leads me to not want to resort to that solution.

I've browsed Ask Ubuntu as well as Google, and this issue has yet to arise for this flavor of Ubuntu. What is bothersome is going to Compiz Config has Unity Tweak Tool available but no check box? Also, when trying to select the checkbox within its selection reports conflicts with a variety of commands.

If anyone has any solutions, I would greatly be in your favor!

As requested by Seth, here is the output output of apt-cache policy unity-tweak-tool:

```
  1 unity-tweak-tool:¬                                                                                
  2   Installed: 0.0.6¬
  3   Candidate: 0.0.6¬
  4   Version table:¬
  5  *** 0.0.6 0¬
  6         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages¬
  7         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status¬
  8      0.0.4 0¬
  9         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages¬
```

Moreover, when I call dconf watch / on terminal -absolutely no results are echoed when I either change items in my system preferences nor my unity tweak tool:
[image: hot-corners-bot-applying]

There is a ppa for calibre in which I notice that it threw an error for an amd64 binary -similar to the amd64 package above. Could these two errors be related to a bigger issue wihh amd64?

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: It's not a solution, but I suspect the problem is some boolean getting flipped during an upgrade and something else remembering the old value. -- another possibility that came up in chat is the gconf/dconf move.

Comment: Make sure you are up to date: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. If it installs any packages, reboot and try again. You might also try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up any leftover dependencies.

Comment: Maybe some file is read-only... it could happen.

Comment: @Seth I have tried both extensions twice and with no success. I'm planning on doing a fresh install -even though I really don't want to. Hopefully this doesn't happen again as this anomaly has to have a cause. That cause however, is hard to root. I thank everyone for their suggestions and hopefully, before Friday, we can come up with a solution to this problem.